# IIS URL Rewrite: Redirect only the domain not the subfolders

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a domain example.com and I just want these exact domain to be redirected to new-example.com.

All the subfolders are redirected to different domains. That works fine.

But how can I achieve the redirect of only exactly example.com ?

I have this, but I does not work.

```
<rule name="Redirect Rule example.com" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/$" />       
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.new-example.com" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the error.

It needs to be

```
<rule name="Redirect Rule example.com" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^$" />       
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.new-example.com" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
```